# Copy-paste picture with random range in VBA and Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code. I wanted to paste the picture in specific range, i tried different codes but failed. I want it to the top left, Or started in "A1".

```
         Sub CommandButton2_Click()

         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("B5:G32").Select
         Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
         Sheet10.Pictures.Paste.Select

         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate

         End Sub
```

Comment: What did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a recommendation, always try to stay away from `Activate`, `Select` and `Selection`, instead use referenced objects.

The code below will copy the range("B5:G32") from `Sheets(3)` to `Sheets(1)` and will place the picture at Cell A1 (top-left position).

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("B5:G32").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

With Sheet10.Pictures.Paste
    .Left = Range("A1").Left ' <-- setting the left postion to Cell A1
    .Top = Range("A1").Top ' <-- setting the top postion to Cell A1
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Finally! thanks also for the recommendation :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
 Sub CommandButton2_Click()

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate
 Range("B5:G32").Copy  'you can copy directly, in one instruction
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(10).Activate
 Range("A1").Select  'select where you want to paste it
 ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste  
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate

 End Sub
```

Check a working example for paste as image here http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04177936342289971269

Comment: Nothing happens man. Not even paste the picture. Btw thanks for this i'll try different.

Comment: Can you upload somewhere the example?

Comment: You should be looking to code this without selecting / activating. It should then be a bit more performant & easier for others to read. E.g. just use `Sheets(3).Range("B5:G32").Copy`. I think your problem here is by copying the range not the picture object.

Comment: I understood this as copy range and paste it as picture. If different, upload an example at http://www.filedropper.com/ or other service and give additional details on what you want to achieve

Comment: Yes this is a copy range, and paste it as picture to another sheet. 
I want to copy the range ("B5:G52") as picture' and paste it to Sheet1 in a specific cell which is ("A1:or something/etc" )

Comment: (Problem Solved) I just followed the code by Shai Rado. Thanks for all your comments and suggestions.